# ESP32 Bluetooth. Redirecting serial output

Tags: bluetooth, esp32

I have an ESP32 dev board to which I have attached a MMA8451 accelerometer which outputs it's data via serial. Is there an easy way to output the data to a bluetooth serial reciever on an android phone? In part of the code I am using Serial.print statements. Is there a bluetooth equivalent ?

```
// Read the 'raw' data in 14-bit counts
  mma.read();
  Serial.print("X:\t"); Serial.print(mma.x); 
  Serial.print("\tY:\t"); Serial.print(mma.y); 
  Serial.print("\tZ:\t"); Serial.print(mma.z); 
  Serial.println();
```

Comment: yes 

Comment: Good to know. Got any custard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with some quick [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=esp32+bluetooth+virtual+com+port). Or if you want to use the [ESP32-idf](https://www.google.com/search?q=esp32-idf%20bluetooth%20virtual%20com%20port&s=g).

Seems to me that there are two possibilities. You could either use the Arduino [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial) library or [the ESP-IDF SPP GATT CLIENT demo](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/ble_spp_client)

The Arduino solutions looks something like [this](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/03/09/esp32-arduino-serial-communication-over-bluetoth-hello-world/):

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32");
}

void loop() {

  SerialBT.println("Hello World");
  delay(1000);
}
```

The ESP-IDF version is a [bit more complex](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/ble_spp_client/main/spp_client_demo.c), but this is the code to send a periodic heartbeat using the bluetooth api:

```
#ifdef SUPPORT_HEARTBEAT
void spp_heart_beat_task(void * arg)
{
    uint16_t cmd_id;

    for(;;) {
        vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if(xQueueReceive(cmd_heartbeat_queue, &cmd_id, portMAX_DELAY)) {
            while(1){
                if((is_connect == true) && (db != NULL) && ((db+SPP_IDX_SPP_HEARTBEAT_VAL)->properties & (ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE_NR | ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE))){
                    esp_ble_gattc_write_char( spp_gattc_if,
                                              spp_conn_id,
                                              (db+SPP_IDX_SPP_HEARTBEAT_VAL)->attribute_handle,
                                              sizeof(heartbeat_s),
                                              (uint8_t *)heartbeat_s,
                                              ESP_GATT_WRITE_TYPE_RSP,
                                              ESP_GATT_AUTH_REQ_NONE);
                    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }else{
                    ESP_LOGI(GATTC_TAG,"disconnect\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thankyou - Using the arduino method. Much appreciated